# Jasmine: testing function with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a service that wraps ajax calls (*$http*) and returns a promise. In my controller, I resolve the promise with  `MyService.stuff(…).`**`then`**`(fn(data){ $scope.stuff = data; })`

How do I test the value of `$scope.stuff`?

```
// controller
$scope.stuff = false;
$scope.getStuff = function(name)
{
    if ( !angular.isDefined( $scope.users[ name ] ) )
        MyService.stuff( 'get' , username ).then(function(data)
        {   // returns the value of resp.data
            $scope.stuff = $scope.users[ name ] = data;
        });
    else
        $scope.stuff = $scope.users[ name ];
};
```

What I've got for the test looks like this:

```
// test
describe('scope.stuff',function()
{
    it('should initialize as false', function ()
    {   // this passes
        expect(scope.stuff).toBe(false);
    });

    var httpBackend;
    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend){
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));
    it('should have 4 elements', function()
    {   // this stalls
        runs(function()
        {
            httpBackend.whenGET().respond(200,
            { data: [
                {name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'baz'},{name: 'qux'}
            ]});
            scope.getStuff('foo');
        });
        waitsFor(function()
        {
            scope.$apply();
            return scope.stuff;
        });
        runs(function()
        {
            expect(scope.stuff.length).toBe(4);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like your test needs 2 digest cycles.
httpBackend.flush() for simulating server response and scope.$apply() for resolving the promise

Comment: @EitanPeer, that seems to have fixed the stalling! But *MyService* doesn't seem to intercept the httpBackend's response: When I log `scope.stuff` just above the expect, I get the whole object instead of just the value of *data*. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @EitanPeer, nevermind, I'm an idiot. I supplied the payload as an object named *data* that gets put into the response object's *data* obj. Thanks for your help! Would you post your comment as an answer so i can approve it and close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your test needs 2 digest cycles.
httpBackend.flush for simulating server response and scope.$apply for resolving the promise